# Replacing multiple values simultaneously in whole dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have data in many columns like the following in pandas dataframe:

```
col1|   col2|   ...|   col99    |col100
MBs|    Gigabytes|...|  MBs|    |MBs
Megabytes|   GBs|...|Megabytes  |Gigabytes
GB  |   Megabytes|  ...|Gigabytes|Gigabytes
GBs |   GB     |...   |MBs  |Gigabytes
Gigabytes|Megabytes|...|Gigabytes   |Megabytes
```

I have also a dictionary which maps similar values. For example,

```
mapping = {'Megabytes':'MB', 'Gigabytes':'GB', 'MBs':'MB','GBs':'GB', 'GB':'GB',}
```

I want to replace each value in the column with mapped values in the dict. Currently I am trying to do something like this but getting an error. Expected output should be

```
col1|col2|...|col99|col100
MB| GB|...| MB| |MB
MB|GB|...|MB|GB
GB |MB|...|GB|GB
GB|GB|...|MB|GB
GB|MB|...|GB|MB

# My current implementation
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).replace('GBs', 'GB').replace('MBs', 'MB').replace('Megabytes', 'MB').replace('Gigabytes', 'GB'))
```

Can someone guide me a correct and faster way of doing this ?

Comment: Are __all__ your columns are of `object` (string) dtype?

Answer (score 3):

`pd.DataFrame.replace` can take a dictionary of dictionaries where the first level of keys specify the column to apply the value when replacing.

We can use a dictionary comprehension to filter only those columns that are of `dtype == object`

```
df.replace({c: mapping for c in df if df[c].dtype == object})

  col1 col2 col99 col100
0   MB   GB    MB     MB
1   MB   GB    MB     GB
2   GB   MB    GB     GB
3   GB   GB    MB     GB
4   GB   MB    GB     MB
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.loc[:, df.dtypes=='object'] = df.select_dtypes(['object']).replace(mapping, regex=True)
```

This will apply `mapping` only to `string` columns

---

If **all** your columns are of string (`object`) dtype:

```
df = df.replace(mapping, regex=True)
```

or as @JohnGalt has proposed in the comment:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: mapping[x])
```

Comment: I'd use replace too. `df.applymap(lambda x: mapping[x])` is another alternative, assuming all values have mapping.

Comment: @JohnGalt, yes, we can use `.applymap()` too :) Actually in the last Pandas versions it got much faster - it was slower in the past...

Comment: I swear if I went back and retagged the appropriate questions, you'd have a gold badge for `replace`

Comment: `df.replace({c: mapping for c in df if df[c].dtype == object})`

Comment: @piRSquared, this is nice! Please turn it into an answer